# Remove HTML tags and formatting text

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I would like to remove HTML tags between text and change newline to space. I'm using this pattern below but it is not perfectly. It adds two or more space between text. How to fix this pattern?

```
replace(/(&nbsp;|<([^>]+)>)/ig, ' ');
```

Comment: maybe you can provide some input and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code and check

```
replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

**UPDATE**

You can do this way,

```
var html = 'Example: &nbsp;<h1></h1><p></p><div>&nbsp;</div><div>CONTENT</div>&nbsp;';
html = html.replace(/\s|\n|&nbsp;/g, ' ');
html = html.replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '');
```

Output will be like this,

```
Example:   CONTENT
```

Play around the above solution & you will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'll do what you want:
(See comments in my snippet)

```js
// Input data
var input_data = `My<div><br>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div><p>Content</p>`;
console.log("Input:", input_data);

// Creates html element with Input data
var elm = document.createElement('div');
elm.innerHTML = input_data;

// Use native function '.innerText' to get rid of the html,
// then replace new lines by spaces, and multiple spaces by only one space
output_data = elm.innerText.replace(/\n/g, ' ').replace(/[\s]+/g, ' ');
console.log("Output:", output_data);
```

Hope it helps!